# Amazon S3 crossdomain.xml always shows 403 Forbidden

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, cross-domain, http-status-code-403, plupload

I am using plupload to upload files directly to Amazon S3. I added crossdomain.xml file into Amazon.When I try the sample code given in [plupload](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/examples/jquery/s3.php) to upload files to S3 I am getting

> GET http://xxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/crossdomain.xml 403 (Forbidden)

My crossdomain.xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-     policy.dtd">
 <cross-domain-policy>
 <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
 </cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Any ideas on this? I seem to having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have public read acl set on the object or getobject permissions on the bucket?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ACLOverview.html